# How to decrease of a sound in Jython?

Tags: java, python, audio, jython

I want to decrease the sample value in a sound linearly, starting from the very first sample `[0]`, which would have the max value (32767), and the last one [sound length end] having the smallest possible value (-32767). To do this I'd assume you could use the format `y=mx+b`. Since `m = y2-y1/x2-x1` I have:

```
def decreasing(sound):
  length = getLength(sound)
  max = 32767.0
  min= -32767.0
  for sample in getSamples(sound):
    setSampleValue(sound, int((((min-max) / (length)) * (index)) + max))
```

The problem I'm having is with the *x* in `y=mx+b`, *x* is the *index* I think as it is the value on the x plain you get to find the sample value (y). However when I run the code I get:

> The error was:index ... Name not found globally

Since I'm not sure how to define it. So basically what I'm asking is how do I make this number:

[image]

*x* in my equation.

Comment: Please paste the error and traceback instead of trying to describe it vaguely.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your own posts. That is inappropriate behaviour. By posting content on the site, you have licensed it perpetually and irrevocably. You cannot take it away whenever you want to. Do you have a specific reason to want to see it removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that getSamples() returns a list, you probably want something like this:

```
for index, sample in enumerate(getSamples(sound)):
    setSampleValue(sample, int((((min-max)/length) * index) + max))
```